# 2-way Graph Partitioning problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, terminology, partition-problem

We have a graph $G=(V,E)$ and we need to divide this graph into two clusters $A$ and $B$. Some pairs of vertices $u$, $v$ should not be in the same cluster, and we define an edge $(u,v) \in E$. The total cost of a solution is the total number of edges with endpoints both in the *same* cluster. My goal is to find an algorithm that returns the optimal solution that *minimizes* this total cost. The solution does *not* have to be balanced in the sense that the clusters should be of the same size.

I was wondering what the general name for this problem is and what a proper algorithm is that can solve this efficiently. By a colleague I was pointed into the direction of using a (nice) *tree decomposition*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a **[maximum cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut)** in the graph – maximizing the number of edges between the partitions minimizes the number within them.

Unfortunately, Max Cut is **NP**-hard on general graphs and also hard to approximate. There's a polynomial-time algorithm on planar graphs, if that's of any use to you.